# GameCenter - log player out

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, game-center

I've got an iPhone game that I've just added GameCenter support to, and everything seems to be working ok. But, as someone who doesn't use GameCenter, I've added an option so that users can turn it off. The only problem is that once the GKLocalPlayer is signed into GameCenter, I can't see a way to sign them out - which means that if the user is signed in, then disables GameCenter support, my app won't use it, but the GK library still signs the user back in every time my app comes back to foreground, until the app is terminated. I don't want this to happen!

Is there any way to log the local player out of GameCenter, or at least stop the GK framework from logging you back in every time your app becomes active?

Comment: You could try setting `localPlayer.authenticateHandler = nil;`

Comment: The `authenticateHandler` must not be nil.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to log out of game center from within the app. The best solution is to add a boolean flag indicating the user's login status:

```
BOOL gameCenterOn = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"gameCenterOn"];
```

Default it to YES, and just set it to NO if the user opts out of game center in your app.

You'll also have to check the value of that flag before processing any game center requests. (Including the `[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:` calls in the app delegate.)

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I'm doing already. The problem is that once you're signed in, GK seems to automatically re-authenticate the local player whenever your app loses and then regains foreground status, and I can't find a way to tell it not to. So if a user signs into GK, then decides they want to disable it, my app no longer talks to GameCenter, but any time they task switch back to my app from somewhere else, GK will still re-authenticate behind the player's back. It doesn't *break* anything, but it's going to be using up people's valuable 3G bandwidth needlessly! (i am the OP)

Comment: Why do you want to let people disable game center in your App?  if they have a Game Center account, why not use it?  They can always sign out in the Game Center App if they don't want to use.  What is the scenario that woud have someone signed into Game Center but not want to use it with your App?  Coding around expected behavior is a good warning sign.

Comment: I have a game center account, but I dont use it, because so many apps are *really really bad* at not crashing/doing weird stuff when the connection is dropped. This means that certain other games are constantly asking me to sign in to GameCenter every time they become active, which is incredibly annoying.

Comment: Posted the above comment to soon - its just an option to say 'don't pester me about GC, wether I'm logged in or not', something I wish mroe games had.

Comment: An application will(can) ask you to sign in only 3 times.

Comment: 3 times... for each game! Thank you for adding the option to your game. I despise game center and most games won't stop asking me to sign in.